# Get the session on the two routers

Tags: javascript, express

I have 2 routers

router1

```
app.post ('/ consultations', function (req, res) {

    req.session.nombre = 'administrator';
   console.log ('test', req.session.name); // there the session is saved well
});
```

router2

```
router.get ('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log ('retrieve session', req.session); // exit undefined
}
```

How can I get the session on the two routers?

EDIT:
i created a middleware

```
function mymiddleware(req,res,next){
  req.session.nombre='MiNOMBRE';
}
```

and I try to get the middleware;

```
app.get('/miroute1',mymiddleware,(req,res) => {
      console.log(req.session.nombre);//
```

but never enters
             }

```
 app.get('/miroute2',mymiddleware,(req,res) => {
          console.log(req.session.nombre);//
but never enters
         }
```

Comment: As long as your routers are added to the routing chain AFTER your session management middleware runs, then both routers should have access to the session data.  If one router does not have access to the session property, then it's probably running before the session middleware has run and you need to revise the order in which they are added to the routing chain so the session middleware runs first.  If you show us more relevant code, we could help you more specifically (like where these routers are added to the chain and where your session middleware is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mymiddleware(req,res,next){
  req.session.nombre='MiNOMBRE';
  next();
}
```

next() will call next middleware in sequence, which in your case is

```
(req,res) => {
      console.log(req.session.nombre);}
```

Comment: app.get('/consultas',mymiddleware, function (req, res) {
    console.log('BBBAAA',req.session);//never enter
})
function mymiddleware(req,res,next){
    console.log('MiddleWARE');// yes enter

Comment: the request is never executed, it only enters the middleware

Answer (score 0):

I think in your middleware you have to call `next()`

Comment: you can expand your answer please